# DataGridView Buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, ado.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView control with the following columns, Item, Price, Qty and 2 DataGridViewButton columns in order to allow increment and decrement of the Qty of the Item in that particular row by clicking on the respective buttons, which will then update the new qty in the database. How can i achieve this? Using ADO.Net for DB.

Comment: What do you need exatly? How to write querry, or something else? Can you please describe your problem?

Comment: I've only created the event handler for both the buttons. How can i capture the value of Qty for that particular row?

Comment: How can i allow the increment/decrement upon button event to be reflected in the datagridview as well as the database?

Comment: Can you please articulate all your `requirements pointwise and format the question properly` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the datagridview's CurrentCell property to get the row, and then get the cell value:

```
object val = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells["QTYColumn"].Value;
```